# Share tools in root package.json with all packages

Tags: node.js, npm, lerna, monorepo

I'm building a monorepo using *Lerna* and *npm*. It has a typical structure of a root `package.json` and more packages in subdirectory `packages/*`.

Each package has a script called `build` that depends on `rimraf`, `tsc` and a few other tools.

To build all packages I use `lerna run build`, which works perfectly. But when running `npm run build` in one of the packages individually, it fails because the shared tools, `rimraf` etc, are not found.

As I understand it, the import statement looks for packages first in `./node_modules`, and if not found, it looks in `../node_modules`, and so on, until at the root of the file system. But `package.json` scripts seems to only check in `./node_modules/.bin`. And `lerna run` must be doing some magic to make the root `./node_modules/.bin` be available to the build script.

How is this supposed to work? Do I have to add all tools to all packages?

Comment: Any luck? Trying to use a "root" install of eslint rather than install in all packages.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to add different build scripts to the root `package.json` like so:

```
"build": "lerna run build --parallel",
"build:packageA": "lerna run build --parallel --scope packageA"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a script in your root `package.json` to use some dependency, i.e.

```
"foo": "rimraf"
```

Then in a `package.json` in a subdirectory, use the `--prefix` flag to run the npm script from the root's package. The below example assumes that your subdirectory package lies at `projects/some-name/package.json`:

```
"foo": "npm run foo --prefix ../.. -- arg-passed-to-rimraf"
```